# The conversion of a date data type to a datetime data type resulted in an out-of-range value

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012

I'm having a table which has one column and it's data type is `Date`

```
Column_name Type    Computed    Length
colunmname  date    no          3
```

How can I convert this datatype to Datetime.

I've tried below but it gives error:

```
ALTER TABLE tableName ALTER COLUMN columnname DATETIME
```

Error:

> Msg 242, Level 16, State 3, Line 1 The conversion of a date data type
>   to a datetime data type resulted in an out-of-range value.

The statement has been terminated.

*Can anyone please help me!*

Comment: `SELECT * FROM tableName where columnname < '17530101'` will find the problem rows for you. But, why are you switching it to `datetime` rather than `datetime2`?

Comment: @DavidG - both the title of the question and two mentions in the body of the question indicate that it is currently of type `date`.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8430611/convert-column-from-date-to-datetime-sql-server

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever - thanks I have converted it to Datetime2 and its working now. thanks again. :D

Comment: You might also want to read [Why you should never use datetime again.](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/cdnsoldevs/2011/06/22/why-you-should-never-use-datetime-again/)

Comment: @ZoharPeled - thank a lot for the link!!

Answer (score 1):

It worked like this for me

```
ALTER TABLE NAME_TABLE ALTER COLUMN NAME_COLUMN  datetime2 not null
```